# Neo4j 2.2.4 ERROR Could not send response error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

Tags: neo4j, runtime-error, cypher

I received above error while executing a Cypher statement. Here is more from the log:

```
06:58:28.837 [qtp2134377029-224] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - Could not send response error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
06:58:47.109 [qtp2134377029-224] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response - Committed before 400 org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1@6e581b9c
06:58:47.110 [qtp2134377029-224] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /db/data/cypher
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
```

What does this mean? I am using neo4j 2.2.4 enterprise version.

Comment: provide more context, what cypher statement did you sent?

Comment: I figured out this is a parser version that i used incorrectly